# Can one use the Emergency WiFi network at Mexico City International Airport (MEX) airport if no disaster is ongoing?

Tags: airports, mexico, wifi, mexico-city, mex

I read on https://aeropuerto-mex.com/en/faqs/ ([mirror](https://archive.ph/113B1)):

> Is there free WiFi Internet access? The CDMX WiFi network service is free and for an unlimited time in AICM [=MEX airport] in the boarding rooms, corridors and food area of ​​T1 and T2. **It also has an Emergency WiFi network (for first aid use in case of disaster)**.

I Googled `"emergency wifi network" mex airport` but couldn't find any information beyond this quote.

Can non-first-aid individuals use the Emergency WiFi network at Mexico City International Airport (MEX) airport if no disaster is ongoing?

Comment: I think the downvotes say it all - if its labelled “for emergency use” just leave it alone, no ifs, no buts, no maybes.

Comment: @Moo "first aid use **in case of** disaster". For example, the emergency lane on the highway can be used by non-emergency vehicles in some places when there's no emergency.

Comment: And when everyone uses those lanes at peak and theres an emergency? Theres a damn good reason why this stuff should be protected when not in use - relying on the public to get off the emergency infrastructure when theres an emergency is simply stupid.  Just dont use it in the first place, consider having to slum it on the public wifi as a first world problem and dont be part of the problem.

Comment: @Moo I'm not making the rules, just informing you.

Comment: I don't understand why, but in a few places there have been experiments (and as far as my knowledge goes, in some of those places they have made those permanent) with the emergency lanes on highways being usable at certain times. That's no reason to assume that other emergency services work the same way, especially not in other countres (I don't know if Mexico has had any of the mentioned experiments). Furthermore: many airports are so big that you would not know if somebody needed the emergency network in another part, and it's possible to make the network so your usage interferes.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity very doable e.g. kickoff all wifi users and add warning/password/mac filter/etc. if disaster.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt and that wastes someones time and effort to do that.  Leave the emergency facilities alone, using the public wifi isnt going to kill you - using the one for emergencies might kill someone tho.

Comment: Can you detect the WiFi using your mobile?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler no idea. The previous commentators  focused on the moral aspect, whereas my interest lies in the technical and legal aspects.  According to the existing answer by mlc,  the answer is negative  assuming that no emergency is ongoing: "enable a wifi network in case of emergency."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most information I could find about the wifi network at the CDMX Airport is in [this press conference from July 8, 2020](https://youtu.be/a4dm0o1tqpQ?t=729) where it was announced that the network would be available starting from July 13 of that year. [José Merino](https://twitter.com/PPmerino/status/1281040624892776448), head of Mexico City's [digital public innovation agency](https://adip.cdmx.gob.mx/) announced that:

> Finally, the city's airport will have a free and extensive internet network, in both terminal 1 and terminal 2. It's a free service for its users; they don't have to be customers of any business, they don't have to register, they don't have to give any personal data in order to be able to visit any website, with the exception of course of sites that the businesses have identified as risky, but outside of that, the truth is that there's no restriction.
>
> It also serves, like the rest of the city's access points that I've talked about, to enable a wifi network in case of emergency.

[my translation based in part on youtube's automated transcription]

The on-screen graphic states that the network:

> - Free
> - Unlimited access duration
> - Without content restrictions (except "black lists")
> - Bandwidth of 3/5 Mbps per user to upload and download information
> - Enables an emergency wifi network (for use by first responders in case of disaster)
> - Up to 8000 users simultaneously connected

[my translation]

As you are (apparently) not a first responder, you can not use the emergency network, but you should have no trouble using the public network. I can also confirm that I had no trouble with the public network when I used it in autumn of 2021.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting, I had no idea this was so recent.

Comment: So what does this *actually* mean? There is a *visible* public SSID that your devices can see and freely login to - and there is an additional *hidden* SSID that is known to first responders so their devices can automatically log on to that (unkown and unvisible to the public) SSID; and in addition, this emergency WLAN has priority over the standard WLAN, which is of course unnoticeable as long as it is not in active use? -- So it may be interesting to stand near an emergency responder somewhere and try to find out which SSIDs they are looking for?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen if there is an emergency and the first responders are responding to it, i hope you will prioritize _evacuating safely_ and not trying to shoulder-surf their wifi credentials!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen   My understanding from the quote is that the airport simply activates this Wi-Fi network whenever needed.